# Flask my first code, i have problem with POST

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, post

I started to learn Flask, I have a simple task: make a button, get the name and display on the monitor, seemingly simple, I did and it does not work. The second day I sit on the smoke, could someone help me? Thank you :D

Sorry,
I paste the pictures because StackOF won't let me paste the code - I don't know why... :/

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: No one else has problems posting code as text. Delete this and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are routing `/` to two different functions, move the code from inside `answer` and put it inside `index`.

Comment: Don't copy the `return` from `answer` to `index` . Also, you can avoid using an `else` by making a default value of `name`